# Running fill.js in Rhino?

Tags: javascript, node.js, template-engine, rhino

I'm looking for a templating engine - after intense checking it looks like [fill.js](https://github.com/profit-strategies/fill) can work the way I want: initial data population on the server, thereafter population via JSON in the browser.
For node.js it is well documented, but my backend is Java. So I was wondering how I could use Rhino to run fill.js? A code sample would be very much appreciated.